# About file I/O using socket in python

Tags: python, sockets, file-io

I've been having a problem with coding the file I/O program using a socket in python. The purpose of my server program is to send a text file to the client program via socket. Even though I confirmed that a client program receives some data from a server program, the client can't write the data to the file. What is the problem??? Please help me..

[server.py]

```
import socketserver
from time import sleep

class TCPSocketHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        sock = self.request
        while True:
            with open('imageNames.txt', 'r') as file:
                try:
                    names=file.readlines()
                    for name in names:
                        print(name)
                        sock.send((name.encode('utf-8')))
                except Exception as exc:
                    print(exc)
            sleep(60)

def main():
    HOST, PORT = "192.168.xx.xx", 7799
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), TCPSocketHandler)
    server.serve_forever()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[client.py]

```
import socket

def main():
    HOST, PORT = "192.168.xx.xx", 7799
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        data = (sock.recv(1024)).decode('utf-8')
        with open('imageNames2.txt', 'w') as file:
            try:
                while data:
                    print(data)
                    file.write(data)
                    data = (sock.recv(1024)).decode('utf-8')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: are you getting any exceptions?? how can you confirm that there is some data being received?? I hope you understand how data gets transferred over socket.

Comment: @PrakashPalnati thank you for your comment!! I could confirm that through "print(data)" in client.py

Answer (score 0):

**Big Edit**

After some more digging I found that what I wrote before was only partially correct. The real reason is the buffering, both in Python and on the file system level.

If a TextIO object is created, there's a buffer that accumulates input to avoid excessive system calls. Once this buffer fills up, the content will be flushed towards the file system where it might end up in another buffer until this one fills up and the content is finally written to the file.
Now, the content manager exiting, thus internally calling close() on the TextIO implicitly enforces flushing the buffers.

With the loop in the server sleeping for 60 seconds, probably both, you and I have not been patient enough to wait for the buffers to fill up to a level that triggers flushing to see content in the file on disk.

If you want to enforce every chunk that the client receives to show up in the file immediately, you'll have to explicitly flush the TextIO buffer and call os.fsync() to trigger flushing of the file system buffer as well.

So, here's how you could alter the client while keeping the server in its infinite loop over the file content:

```
import os
import socket


def main():
    HOST, PORT = "127.0.0.1", 7799
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
        sock.connect((HOST, PORT))
        data = (sock.recv(1024)).decode('utf-8')
        with open('imageNames2.txt', 'w') as file:
            try:
                while data:
                    file.write(data)
                    file.flush()
                    os.fsync(file.fileno())
                    print(data)
                    data = (sock.recv(1024)).decode('utf-8')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please note that in some IDEs, such as PyCharm, the new file might not show up in the project overview until the file has been closed. On the file system level, however, it does exist.

Also, my earlier side note about losing the first line was wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply. Thanks to your comment, I can understand why the problem occurred. However, I have to make the server program sending the text file periodically(one minute) to client program. Is there no other way?

Comment: Just so I understand correctly. You want the full content of the file to be sent to the same client, using the same session repeatedly every minute? The client should never cleanly disconnect?

Comment: I kept thinking about it, it is better the client should never disconnect. In addition, I don't have any other way than using the same session. I would like to explain more in detail if I speak english well, I'm so sorry I can't.

Comment: OK, I did some more research and corrected my answer. Also, added some possible solution. Maybe this helps somehow

Comment: I corrected it by modifying a bit with your advice. I would like to thank you very much for your help and learn harder.